# Recommendation for Windows Server 2012 R2 start menu

Tags: windows-server, menu

Firstly, interested in whether or not it's a good idea to change the start menu on a server, in a similar fashion to Windows desktop OS.

If so, does anyone have any recommendations? Moving from 2008R2 simple start menu to 2012R2 the start menu / tiles is a nightmare. Recommendations welcomed.

Ideally we would use a free utility; however if we could pay for something that offered good functionality, and was trustworthy, we would be willing to pay, depending on how much it is of course.

Comment: What features do you need (see: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185))? Must it be free, or are you willing to pay (how much)?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us exactly what you don't like in the default start menu, with screenshots if needed. We will then reopen. Thanks!

Comment: I think the simplest explanation is that I would like the Windows Server 2008 R2 start menu in 2012! Don't like the tiles, or having to scroll down to the apps and then then across. Too big, needs to be more concise.

Answer (score 1):

[Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) maybe?

> Classic Shell works on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 and their server counterparts (Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2016). Both 32 and 64-bit versions are supported. The same installer works for all versions.
>
> Classic Shell™ is free software that improves your productivity, enhances the usability of Windows and empowers you to use the computer the way you like it. The main features are:
>
> Highly customizable start menu with multiple styles and skins, 
>       Quick access to recent, frequently-used, or pinned programs
>       Find programs, settings, files and documents,
>       Toolbar and status bar for Windows Explorer,
>       Caption and status bar for Internet Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks look like this will do the job. Safe to run on production servers?

Comment: I don't know, but a lot of people use and love Classic Shell so I don't see why not.